# Power series interval of convergence $ x^k$ multiplication/division

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series

1. If we have a power series and we multiply it by $x^k$ where $k$ is fixed natural number, does the resulting series have the exact same interval of convergence?
2. Also if we have power series starting with $a x^k$ and we divide it by $x^k$, does the resulting series have the same interval of convergence?

Here I mean term by term multiplication / division with $x^k$.

I think both are true and can be proved by using the definition of the convergence of function series. But I wonder if I am missing something.

3. Also if the old function sum was $S(x)$, is the new function sum $S(x) x^k$ and $S(x) / x^k$, respectively?

Comment: Since $S(x)$ has already converged, multiplying or dividing by one term won't affect it,

Comment: Yes, but I am still somewhat confused. Especially regarding the point x=0.

Comment: Just distinguish the cases. If $x=0$ then....

Comment: Yes, I know... But then what happens with question 3)... That is where I am getting confused.

Comment: When $x=0$, multiplication leads to $0$.  When dividing, at $x=0$ only the first term  remains.  I don't understand why you are having a problem.